# Provide the live podcast in audio-only form

Tags: support, podcast

I have [endless](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512?m=1191067#1191067) [problems](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512?m=1151738#1151738) [with](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512?m=1233082#1233082) [Livestream](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512?m=1233544#1233544); every 30 seconds or so it suddenly loses its connection and ends up on this screen:

[image: Screenshot of Livestream loading]

I have RealPlayer flashbacks every week during the podcast. Changing the quality doesn't help (and it forgets my setting anyway every time the loading screen comes up -- it just switches back to "medium")

Fortunately, I'm not particularly attached to seeing Joel and Alex sit at their desks while I listen to the podcast. Is it possible to get an live audio-only stream that doesn't involve Livestream in any way?

Comment: I've got no objection to adding an audio only feed - do you have any suggestions for services that provide this though?  Everything I've seen in the past requires you to set up your own server and bandwidth and that's not an optimal solution for us.  Looking for something like Livestream/Ustream but for audio only.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to join the live stream late. No dice, as per a few other [late](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2566594#2566594) [joiners](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2566610#2566610) in the chat room.

So I got my Google on and come across these guys: [Stream Guys](http://www.streamguys.com/streamingservices/livestreaming.html).

Perhaps they could be used to provide an audio only live stream.